# How to import the contacts from Outlook to an android phone ?

Tags: contacts, lumia-540

I am using Microsoft Lumia 540. I want to import the contacts that I stored in outlook to Redmi 3s Prime phone. Is it possible ?
Its going to be a tedious job retyping and saving 600 odd contacts into a new phone.

Comment: Are you talking about the desktop version of Outlook, or the web based outlook.com service?

Comment: I am talking about the Outlook account of mine in which my contacts are saved when my SIM card's memory became full.

Comment: Can you not just connect to the same outlook.com account then?

Comment: Also, can you clarify if you're trying to import to your Lumia 540 (per the question), or to an Android phone (per the title)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you want to share you contacts to third party to import contacts
>   from outlook, you can skip to Step 8

1. Sign-In to your Windows Live (Hotmail) account using a desktop computer: [Windows Live (Hotmail) Login Page](https://login.live.com/)
2. While on the main window, press the drop-down arrow before the “Outlook” and choose “People”.
   [image]
3. In “People” page, select “Manage” and choose “Export”.
   [image]
4. Now, It will ask you, which contacts do you want to export. Select `Contacts` if you only want to export outlook contacts.

[image]

5. Now press “Export” which is on top of window and store the exported contacts file `WLMContacts.csv` on your computer (e.g. on your Desktop).
6. Now, Sign-In to your Google account using a desktop computer.
7. In the main Gmail window, press the drop-down arrow next to “Gmail” and choose “Contacts”. or directly go to this [contacts link](https://contacts.google.com/preview/all)
8. In Contacts page, press “More” menu and select “Import”.
   [image]

> Here you can see that google gives us option to import contact from outlook.com. Here, **ShuttleCloud**, a third party, will take care of your import and they have access to our contacts data, including names & email addresses. So, select this option if you are agree to ShuttleCloud's Terms of Use and Privacy Policy. By this option you can exclude all other steps.

9. Now Select the “CSV or VCard file” button.
10. It will prompt you to go to `old google contacts` Select it.
11. In Contacts page, press “More” menu and select “Import”. 
    [image]
12. Navigate to the location where you saved the Windows Live Contacts file (WLMContacts.csv) in the  previous step and “Open” it.
13. Finally, press the “Import” button and wait until the import process is completed.